# How to cut off question mark in url with functions.php

Tags: functions

I use directive .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)appId=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)q=
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1.html? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

The problem would be solved if this `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$` replace with this `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?`

But this directive does **not work** on the Litespeed server. That's for sure, I contacted the developers of this server.

How to cut (redirect) to a link without a question mark **via** function.php?

example:
if open **website.com/post-name.html?** >>>redirect>>> **website.com/post-name.html**

Sorry for my English.

Comment: 1. "I use directive .htaccess" - what does it really do? 2. "How to cut (redirect) to a link without a question mark" - you mean if the URL *ends with* **just** `?`, i.e. no query string parameters specified? 3. What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to cut the `?`? What does doing that solve?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The Yandex search engine takes somewhere and tries to index links with a question mark at the end. I want to fix this.

Comment: So I've posted an answer, but have you tried [this](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/robot-workings/allow-disallow.html#allow-disallow__asterisk-dollar), i.e. something like `User-agent: Yandex Disallow: /*?$` ? You may also find something helpful [here](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/yandex-indexing/removing-from-index.html).

Comment: The solution to the problem at the site level seems to me to be optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, which uses the [`parse_request` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_request/): (you can add other conditions, e.g. check whether `$wp->query_vars['name']` is not empty, if you want to)

```php
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse_400900_parse_request', 1 );
function wpse_400900_parse_request( $wp ) {
    // Redirect if the URL ends with a ? like https://example.com?
    if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) &&
        ltrim( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' ) === "{$wp->request}?"
    ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( $wp->request ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what is needed!